# QT/QML hindi font support

Tags: qt, character-encoding, qml, hindi

I am trying to create an application with hindi font support. Text written in english is not displayed in hindi. But If i write it in hindi it is displaying in hindi.

```
    FontLoader { id: hindi
    source: "/home/sakshi/development/adt-bundle-linux-x86/sdk/platforms/android-17/data/fonts/DroidSansDevanagari-Regular.ttf";
}

Text{
 x: 149
 y: 348
 width: 428
 height: 44
 text: "\nजोड़े आपको दुनिया से"
 font.family: hindi.name
 }
```

with this text will be displayed as जोड़े आपको दुनिया से

```
FontLoader { id: hindi;
source: "/home/sakshi/development/adt-bundle-linux-x86/sdk/platforms/android-17/data/fonts/DroidSansDevanagari-Regular.ttf";
}

Text{
 x: 149
 y: 348
 width: 428
 height: 44
 text: "\nWelcome"
 //text: hindi.status == FontLoader.Ready ? 'Loaded' : 'Not loaded'
 font.family: hindi.name
}
```

in this case output is "welcome".
 Can any one tell me how to change the font to hindi? Is there any way to translate from english to hindi?

Answer (score 1):

Qt would not know the equivalent of "Welcome" in Hindi, or any other language for that matter. The proper way to add Hindi support to your application would be localization. You could start from [QtQuick Internationalization](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/internationalization.html) and [Internationalization with Qt](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/internationalization.html)

Comment: Hi lijo, thanks for the reply. i went though the link. it helped me. Is there any way to write it in hindi? if i don't want to translate.. some thing like this if i write "suswagat" and the display should be in hindi fonts???

Comment: What you are asking is transliteration. Neither transliteration nor translation can happen automatically. Both requires you to provide a mapping of strings from english to hindi as mentioned in the links.