# Hindi character not recognized by Visual Studio 2012 ASP.NET Design Page

Tags: asp.net

I am using the Hindi language in Visual Studio 2012, it is showing square boxes instead of Hindi characters as shown in the figure.
[image]

Comment: It means you didn't save the page as UTF8, the default for Visual Studio. Or that you *didn't* use the default UTF8 encoding in the page. Or the text was stored in `varchar` fields in the database instead of `nvarchar`. Without any code it's impossible to help more except to say that Visual Studio, .NET and ASP.NET work with Unicode just fine - SO itself is an ASP.NET web app that stores text in `nvarchar` columns and can display any text just fine, including Chinese

Comment: Check [this question for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20758906/qt-qml-hindi-font-support) `जोड़े आपको दुनिया से` appears just fine. I simply copied the characters in the comment.

Comment: This happened in a designer page where we can see the preview of our asp.net page

Comment: What designer page? Post the *code* not screenshots. Post the ASPX page content. I just proved that there are no special requirements for Hindi. Something in that page is wrong. Perhaps it wasn't saved as UTF8? Perhaps the data came from a database field or file that *doesn't* use Unicode? Perhaps the page has a wrong encoding hardcoded in it? Perhaps the *application* does ?

Comment: in the code level, it running good and in the browser, it shows the desired result. but in the design page, it gives this like output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the Mangal font in the system, solves the problem of boxes

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "Hindi font". There is Devanagari script used not just in Hindi but in a good number of other most used languages in India. Now, there are no "English" or "Latin" or "Arabic" or "Devanagari" fonts. The fonts supporting Unicode are universal but they can support different sub-sets of Unicode code points.Try to add a font thatt supports Hindi letters in your design page and remember to add meta tag such as `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

Comment: ASP.NET uses UTF8 by default. .NET strings are Unicode. *Browsers* don't depend on specific fonts either, which is why people can post SO questions about Devanagari or Chinese script without contacting the SO admins. I suspect the OP made a change that broke this.

Comment: This happened in a designer page where we can see the preview of our asp.net page